# Bypassing password authentication in example PHP

Tags: php

I have pseudocode of the following script:

```
  $pass = '...';
  $answer = '....'

  extract($_GET);

  if (($inp)) {
    if ($inp === get_contents($pass)) {
      return $answer
    } else {
      echo "Wrong!"
    }
  }
```

My task is to find out the $answer variable. I have an HTML form which passes the input parameter from the field into this script using the GET method. What kind of attacks could this script be vulnerable to? I am a complete beginner to this stuff, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I read on the PHP website that extract() with $_GET is a very bad idea. Could it be because it makes XSS attacks possible against this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) imports variables into the current symbol table from an array. The `get_contents` might actually be [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) which reads a file into a string. The file could be either on the local filesystem or from the Internet via HTTP.

1. If you know the contents of the text file referenced in `$pass` you know the password you should have in `$inp`, but you don't have that file nor its location.
2. `$_GET['pass']` becomes `$pass` because there's the `extract($_GET);`. Hence, by adding a GET variable you can change the password required for printing the answer.

I would try a file with predictable contents, e.g. `?pass=/etc/hostname&inp=server.example.com%0A` – the *Line Feed* character `%0A` is required, because `/etc/hostname` ends with a newline.

Comment: Hi. I have already tried something like index.html/?pass=abc&inp=abc but it does not work in this scenario. Can you please clarify if that is not what you meant?

My question is, even if I could change the $pass by using GET variable in URL, wouldn't it change again when get_contents() is used in comparison as it will replace the string with the content from; let's say a file?